# how to create subsite with custom template using powershell script

Tags: powershell, site-template, site

I have created site collection.under this site collection I need to create another subsite.the site template for subsite is custom template which is uploaded via solution gallery. how can I achive this using powershell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using power shell and CSOM by following below steps .

Once the custom template is uploaded into the solution gallery of the site collection execute the below commands in Powershell:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$Site = "SiteCollectionURL"
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Site)
```

## List Custom Templates

```
$Templates = $Context.Site.GetWebTemplates("1033","0")
$Context.Load($Templates)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
$Templates | Where {$_.Name -like "*{*" } | Select Name, Description
```

This will list out all the custom templates available in the gallery.

And execute the below commands to create the subsite using the custom template:

## Create Sub-Web using the Custom Template

```
$WCI = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebCreationInformation
$WCI.WebTemplate = "{516EB07D-8711-4B9F-A3AD-097B28C5CDDF}#MyCustomTemplate"
$WCI.Description = "MyNewSubSite"
$WCI.Title = "MyNewSubSite"
$WCI.Url = "MyNewSubSite"
$WCI.Language = "1033"
$SubWeb = $Context.Web.Webs.Add($WCI)
$Context.ExecuteQuery().
```

courtesy : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fromthefield/2015/10/21/create-a-subsite-web-using-a-custom-template-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell-and-csom/